# Cleaning removed branches

Tags: git, git-branch

Does `git fetch --all --prune` clears all removed branches regardless which branch I am?
Or should this be run in `master` branch only?

Comment: Current branch doesn't matter here, no.

Comment: @RomainVALERI what if the current branch is removed? Would one be moved to a detached head state?

Comment: a `fetch` won't remove any local branches, only local refs of the remote branches. By the way, if you have only one remote repo, your `--all` can be omitted. It doesn't stand for "all branches" but "all remotes"

Answer (score 1):

Fetching doesn't remove local branches. If you want to remove them from local as well you can run `git fetch --prune` and then this:

`git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `git fetch --all` means to fetch from all *remotes*.  Most clones have only *one* remote, named `origin`.  So `--all` means nothing in this case.  It's only when:

```
$ git remote
```

lists more than one remote that `--all` does anything: if you have, for instance, both `origin` and `upstream`, `git fetch --all` means the same thing as `git fetch origin; git fetch upstream`.

Meanwhile, as [Felipe Cabargas answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51771214/1256452) (and I upvoted), the `--prune` flag tells your Git to remove *remote-tracking names* (not branch names!) that no longer exist on the remote.  For instance, suppose you just have the one remote named `origin`.  On `origin`, you have a branch named `master` as usual.  You also used to have two feature branches: `feature-short` and `feature-tall`.  So you ran

```
$ git fetch
```

and now *you* have, in *your* Git repository:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/feature/short
  origin/feature/tall
  origin/master
```

Now someone has *deleted* `feature/short` from `origin` because it is all done.  If you just run `git fetch`, your still have `origin/feature/short`.  But if you run `git fetch --prune`, *your* Git will delete *your* `origin/feature/short`.

What if you've created your own `feature/short`?  Well, that's *your* branch.  That's not a copy of `origin`'s `feature/short` at all!<sup>1</sup>  *Your* Git will leave *your* branches alone.  Your Git is copying `origin`'s branches, such as `feature/short` and `feature/tall`, to *your* **remote-tracking names** such as `origin/feature/short` and `origin/feature/tall`.  Prune will remove your *remote-tracking* names, but won't touch your *branches*.

---

<sup>1</sup>It may have started out as a copy, and maybe you even *want* it to *stay* a copy.  But it is *your* branch name, to do with as you will.  If all you want is to keep track of origin's `feature/short`, you might as well just use your `origin/feature/short`, which your Git will *automatically update* to track `origin`'s `feature/short`.  That's why `origin/feature/short` is a *remote-tracking name*, and not a branch name: it *tracks* the remote's branch, by being updated on every `git fetch`.

If you set up `git fetch` to prune it, it will also be automatically deleted when appropriate.  If you *don't* want that to happen, you can either tell `git fetch` to *not* prune, or you can make an actual local branch that's all your own.